# h1 element dissappears to the top when I use event listener and hover the mouse over text content

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mouseover

I wanna increase the height of the navbar with mouseover it, It is working fine when I hover over the nav element, but goes nuts when I actually hover over the text element of h1, I'm a beginner and [images attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfAs6.png)

```
<nav>
  <h1>My Page</h1>
</nav>

const nav = document.querySelector("nav");   

nav.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
  event.target.classList.add("height100");
});

nav.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
  event.target.classList.remove("height100");
});
```

Comment: Question is unclear. Imagine reading this without any other context. Things that are missing: (1) code for css class `height100`. (2) what do you expect to happen __EXACTLY__ (maybe post a picture of the desired behavior VS the actual behavior.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), but provide a proper [mre] of issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note, instead of using javascript to do that, try creating a CSS class on hover, like this:

```css
#my-navbar {
  /*your navbar styles*/
}
#my-navbar:hover {
  /*your navbar styles when hovering over it*/
}
```

```html
<nav id="my-navbar">
  <h1 id="my-navbar-title">My Page</h1>
</nav>
```